# Does Visual Studio 2022 Community installed in offline environment requires sign in after 30 days from installation?

Tags: ide, visual-studio-2022, license-key

I have just installed Visual Studio 2022 community in my PC that has no internet connection.

I skipped the sign in process at the beginning, but I noticed from a few sources that the sign in will be ultimately needed after 30 days of use. Currently I do not have a plan to connect my PC online going forward.

The license page in VS community now shows that the "product key is applied", but does anyone have an idea that this will be enough for me to keep use my VS after 30 days from the installation?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot have a community license without logging-in at least once a month to your Microsoft account (so you will need to create an account if you don't already have one). The following link is for 2019, but it also applies to 2022.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/358527/visual-studio-2019-usage-without-internet.html

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking for the same solution, it has proven that the sign-in is needed in order to keep use my VS Community after 30 days from the installation.